# error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: Module not registered in graph

Tags: react-native

i am a newbe in react native
i don't know what is going on with my apps
the node said "error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: Module not registered in graph"
please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU5ov.png)

Answer (score 17):

This error usually occurs when you install a new module (while packager is open).
Firstly you can try close your packager and run react-native run-ios. If this approach does not help, you can try delete node modules directory and npm install again. But i believe first approach will work.

Comment: Fixed it for me. I was getting this error because i created a new folder with new index.js in there, and for some reason whenever I do this I need to restart packager.

Comment: Starting the bundler with `--reset-cache` should resolve this. In my case that means `yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: I have killed my terminal and rebuild the app (react-native run-android). It resolved this problem.